# Edit text format

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am facing problem while sending edit text data to server and retrieve from other end. I am writing content in edit text area like following way.

```
Hello,
    My I have sent document please find it.

Thanks & Regards,
    Mr.XYZ
```

but retriever end i found the text like below:

**Hello,
    My I have sent document please find it.
Thanks & Regards,
    Mr.XYZ**

Please give me such a way to passing text as i suggested so both side text format will remain same and display in a good manner.

Comment: add your code where you are taking edit text value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to adding `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` if you are displaying it in a `TextView` also add `android:singleLine="false"` to your `EditText` definition.

//--save to string--

```
 Editable e = et.getText();

 String s2 = Html.toHtml(e);
```

//--restore from string--

```
String str = Html.fromHtml(s2).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just put to `\n` separator for new line :

```
String str = "Hello, \n    My I have sent document please find it.\n\n Thanks & Regards,\n     Mr.XYZ";
```

you will get outtput

```
Hello,
 My I have sent document please find it.

Thanks & Regards,
  Mr.XYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following value in xml:

```
<string name="string_name">Hello, \n\t\tMy I have sent document please find it.\n\nThanks &amp; Regards,\n\t\tMr.XYZ</string>
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the new line escape sequence `\n` to `<br>` tag, before sending the data to server.

```
String typedText = editText.getText().toString();
typedText = typedText.replace("\n", "<br>");
```